# SendGrid API v3 Error authorization required when filter E-Mail Activity

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, 400-bad-request

I have an API Key with full access and my account includes the "additional email activity history" (additional payment)

When using a simple PHP request I am getting 400 error and "authorization required"

400 Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [1] => Server: nginx [2] => Date: Thu, 16 Mar 2023 17:20:53 GMT [3] => Content-Type: application/json [4] => Content-Length: 62 [5] => Connection: keep-alive [6] => [7] => ) {"errors":[{"field":null,"message":"authorization required"}]}

Here is my code copied from their documentation

```
require_once 'sendgrid-php.php'; 

    $apiKey = getenv('SG.xxxxxxx');
    $sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);
    
    $query_params = json_decode('{
        "query": "from_email=\"noreply@xxx.com\"",
        "limit": 10
    }');
    
    
    try {
        $response = $sg->client->messages()->get(null, $query_params);
        print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
        print_r($response->headers());
        print $response->body() . "\n";
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo 'Caught exception: '.  $ex->getMessage();
    }
```

Any help will be well appreciated

Comment: When you got "bad request" start validating all your variables to make SURE they are being passed as the type you suspect, that or check all your " " and ' ' and make sure there is no typo.

Answer (score 0):

Just changed the:

```
$apiKey = getenv('SG.xxxxxxx');
```

to:

```
$apiKey = 'SG.xxxxxxx';
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows:
Put `.env` file in the root folder of the project with this line in it:

```
SENDGRID_API_KEY=your_key
```

Set the same line as your user environment variable in Windows.
Restart the machine.